# How can I select dropdown from Selenium POM when my constructor Select(By) is undefined?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, pageobjects

I'm currently trying to select a dropdown from a store page which matches the number of shirts I want to purchase using POM on Selenium. I've followed the instructions listed on a similar answer to this question, but it doesn't appear to work for me.

Here's what I've done so far on a Java file where I store the page objects:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TTPStorePage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public TTPStorePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    By size= By.id("size");
    By reset= By.className("reset_variations");
    By quantity= By.id("quantity_5cb788738ee07");
    By submit=By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']");
    By remove=By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-gtm4wp_product_id,'TS-TTP']");
    By contents=By.className("cart-contents");

    // Right here.
    public WebElement selectSize(int index) {
        Select drop = new Select(size);
        drop.selectByIndex(index);
    }

    public WebElement resetItems() {
        return driver.findElement(reset);
    }

    public WebElement quantityItem() {
        return driver.findElement(quantity);
    }

    public WebElement submitButton() {
        return driver.findElement(submit);
    }

    public WebElement removeItem() {
        return driver.findElement(remove);
    }

    public WebElement cartContents() {
        return driver.findElement(contents);
    }

}
```

Here is a file where I run the test cases themselves:

```
package SimpleProgrammer;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import resources.Base;
import pageObjects.TTPProductPage;
import pageObjects.TTPStorePage;

public class PurchaseApplication extends Base {

    @Test
    public void BuyItem() throws IOException {
        driver=initializeDriver();
        driver.get("https://simpleprogrammer.com/store/products/trust-the-process-t-shirt/");

        TTPProductPage pp= new TTPProductPage(driver);
        pp.TTPButton().click();
        TTPStorePage sp = new TTPStorePage(driver);
        // The problem child.
        sp.selectSize(2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
Select drop = new Select(By.id("size"));
```

But I think it's supposed to be

```
Select drop = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("size")));
```

Comment: Awesome possum, it works man.

Did this solution

 public void selectSize(int index) {
  Select drop = new Select(driver.findElement(size));
  drop.selectByIndex(index);
 }

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this:-

WebDriver’s support classes called “[Select](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-select-methods-to-work-with-dropdowns)”, which provides useful methods for interacting with select options. User can perform operations on a select dropdown and also de-select operation.

```
Select drop = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("size")));
```

For more information go through [this](https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html) link.